# How to remove string value from array in firebase

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having a problem removing a kid string from an array of other aid strings in firebase. When a user creates a group chat, they include sharers. Those sharers are added to an array of strings and then added to firebase when made. Now when a user clicks the leave group chat button, I can't figure out a way to remove the current user's user id from that array, in which I have already checked if their uid is in the array. I have tried everything I can guys, first I tried ref.child("Group Chats").child(groupKey).child("sharers").child(myriad).removeValue, and that did not work, I also tried creating a new array without the current users id, removing the old array and adding the new one to firebase, all did not work, now I turn to some fellow coders. How can I remove the current users did from an array of uids in firebase.

```
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Leave Group Chat", style: .default, handler: {( alert : UIAlertAction) -> Void in
                let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
                    if let keyp = self.groupChats[indexPath.row].key {

                        ref.child("Group Chats").child(keyp).child("sharers").child(uip).removeValue()



                                              }
                    self.groupChat.removeAll()
                    self.pull()
                    self.pullFromSharers()
                    self.tableViewManage.reloadData()

                })
```

[image: Firebase]

Thank you!

Comment: Instead of removeValue go to the appropriate index you want to delete and try setValue(nil)

Comment: I will try that, thanks man

Comment: let me know if it works and I can add it as an answer.

Comment: I tried it and nothing occurred, it did not change anything

Comment: I tried ref.child("Group Chats").child(key).child("sharers").child(did).setValue(nil)

Comment: I am using similar thing in my code and it's working for me let me check for array and let you know

Comment: I would suggest use this to reach the child and then observe are you getting the sharers from which you need to delete or not,  ref.child("Group Chats").child(key).child("sharers").child(did).observe {}

Comment: so observe the event like so  ref.child("Group Chats").child(keyp).child("sharers").child(uid).observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
                            
                            
                            })

Comment: yes , try it and print(snapshot) in it to see are you getting the uid that you want to delete?

Comment: got it let me try

Comment: bizarrely it is saying null, even though it really does exist

Comment: Ok lets do some more debugging try ref.child("Group Chats").child(key).child("sharers").observe() to see whether your shares array is retrieved correctly?

Comment: alright cool ill try it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153079/discussion-between-3stud1ant3-and-randy-windin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After discussion with OP, we have found the solution

Problem is that your path is not calculated correctly, your path was getting the value instead of child, so modify your code as follows:

```
 ref.child("Group Chats").child(keyp).child("sharers").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in 
    if let sharers = snapshot.value as? [String] { 
    for i in 0..<sharers.count { 
    if sharers[i] == uip { 
      ref.child("Group Chats").child(keyp).child("sharers").child("\(i)").removeValue() 
    } 
    } 
    } 

    })
```

Comment: well that actually will not work because there is difference between key and index

Answer (score 0):

i used this simple method in angularjs. i think you also need same thing. try this it will help you.

```
var url = "your db path is here"
var dataObj = {'sharers':''};
   ref(url).set(dataObj).then(function(res) {
      console.log("response:- ",res);
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to remove the entire node by setting to nil like I said in my comment and then setting the node back to the parent. Please check this post as well about firebase arrays.

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/40657455/5123516